# User session connected

Tags: bash, shell, session

When i connect to ssh directly via terminal on unix machine how can i know how many session has been escalated ? i mean

Fisrt i connect as root
#
and

## su bryan

#
and

## su tony

#
and

## su emilie

#

Is it possible to have (a tree like) information of session i connected to ?

ex: *emilie* - tony - bryan - root

Thanks.

Comment: May be `who` is enough?

Comment: thanks Costas ! It is actually not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Linux `ps` commands have the ability to produce process trees, which would show
the processes involved in the present shell:

```
$ ps fuT
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
userone   9591  0.0  0.2  20644  3484 pts/14   Ss   10:50   0:00 bash
root      9743  0.0  0.1  56124  1672 pts/14   S    10:50   0:00  \_ su - root
root      9751  0.0  0.2  21580  4428 pts/14   S    10:50   0:00      \_ -su
root     10112  0.0  0.0  16836  1256 pts/14   R+   10:57   0:00          \_ ps fuT
```